# windows can't read my HDD installed in my dvd slot on MBP

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, optical-drive

I've swapped my dvd drive with an HDD drive on my MBP 2008 non-unibody.
I can read it from MAC os but not from Windows.
I did configure it to be PC compatible...

Anyone knows why it's not seen as an addtional hard drive?

Answer (score 1):

"PC compatible" refers to the way, partitions are written to the disc, I think. If it is HFS formated, Windows does not recognize it. Have you tried to format it with FAT32?

Comment: The Boot Camp 3.x driver pack includes a read-only HFS+ driver.